# Access the context of the calling method in an exported function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `utils` class file that contains a bunch of utility functions used by various other classes/components.

The current scenario contains a `test-utils` class, used by karma unit tests to execute commonly used tasks.

For instance, I have the following method to send input to a native element:

```
export function sendInput(fixture: ComponentFixture<any>, inputElement: any, text: string,  formControl?: AbstractControl): Promise<any> {
    inputElement.value = text;
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    if (!isNullOrUndefined(formControl)) {
        formControl.markAsTouched();
    }

    fixture.detectChanges();
    return fixture.whenStable();
}
```

calling it by:

```
sendInput(fixture, myElement, 'testValue', formElement).then(() => { ... });
```

however I don't want to send parameters like `fixture` through as a paramter, because I know `fixture` is available on the calling context.

**Question**: How do I access the calling context in this scenario? I've tried the following, using an arrow function to pass through the context:

```
export const sendInput = (inputElement: any, value: string, formControl?: AbstractControl): Promise<any> => { 
    // method body
    const context = this;

    // this, context is undefined
}
```

but `this` is still undefined. I don't think I understand the intricacies of javascript well enough to understand why this is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply method on your function:

```
sendInput.apply(this, [myElement, 'testValue', formElement])
```

It allows you to pass your calling context as the first argument, and your array of arguments next.

Comment: Hmm..  I would still just want to call the normal method, `sendInput(...)` and then have access to the calling context, I'm not sure I understand your provided solution. I've also noticed the context in the test fixture is different than a normal `.ts` file, so I'm not sure if I'll be able to achieve what I want to in this scenario